# Find average vector from a vector of vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector containing multiple vectors.

Example: the vector might contain [1,2,3,4] and [5,6,7,8]
How would I find the average of these vectors?

It should output [3, 4, 5, 6].

So this is what I tried:

```
    double sum1 = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    double sum3 = 0;
    double sum4 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < VectorName.size(); i++)
    {
        sum1 = sum1 + VectorName[i][0];
        sum2 = sum2 + VectorName[i][1];
        sum3 = sum3 + VectorName[i][2];
        sum4 = sum4 + VectorName[i][3];
    }
    double avg1 = sum1/VectorName.size();
    double avg2 = sum2/VectorName.size();
    double avg3 = sum3/VectorName.size();
    double avg4 = sum4/VectorName.size();
```

So, my method does work, however, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this... Maybe a pre-built function of some kind?

I am new to c++, so forgive me ;)

Comment: What have you tried? At least give us some code to start with.

Comment: This is a fairly elementary task, you should really try to come up with a solution on your own in order to get started with the language. You will not learn c++ just by studying solutions and not writing your own code ! Start with writing the code in a language you know. Match the abstractions you have used with what c++ has to offer in this regard and try to translate. There are free IDEs online,eg. [ideone](https://ideone.com/), where you can try out code.

Comment: Sorry, let me update my question @Sailanarmo

Comment: @collapsar Yes I definitely agree. I have tried to tackle this problem, but I'm wondering if my method is inefficient. I have updated my question to include what I tried.

Comment: what's `Vector`? and does it have the `+` operator overloaded to use SIMD?

Comment: Sum all of the values for a particular index in a new vector, then divide that by the number of vectors. Not sure why you don't just use a nested loop for what you've shown. What would you do if there were 50 vectors? Make 50 variables and copy/paste 50 lines?

Comment: @AndyM At the beginning, imho, you should not be concerned about efficiency. Focus on understanding the language design principles and write readable code. Don't be too clever - its better to understand your code a month after writing it than gaining another 20% performance (bets are on that the compiler beats you in optimizing anyway ;)).

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks, could you show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: @collapsar Very true ;)

Comment: Use a nested loop.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I've tried, but every attempt has errors that I don't know how to solve... could you send me an example please?

Comment: @AndyM BTW how the avg of  `[1,2,3,4]` and `[5,6,7,8] ` becomes `[3, 4, 5, 6]`? the avg. of first vec shouldn't be `10/4` and for second `18/4`?

Comment: @AndyM: Start by replacing `sum1`, `sum2`, `sum3` and `sum4` with an array, `double sum[4]`, and expressions `sum[0]`, `sum[1]`, `sum[2]` and `sum[3]`. Now consider if you see any sort of loop-able pattern in the resulting code.

Comment: @AndyM I have provided an easy, yet long answer for you to follow. It *is* highly recommended for you to check out some sources and finding out the answer on your own until you finally have no choice (that's the time you come to us).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your question, it seems like you want to loop through the vectors in vertical form instead of the *mass-preferred* horizontal form:-

> [1, 2, 3, 4] + [5, 6, 7, 8] = [6, 8, 10, 12]

It is not a general way and not an easy one either, but let us take on the ride anyway...

**Edit: The source has been edited to be compatible with templates so that you can use anything other than int (like float, double, etc.)**

**1) Create a function that will loop through all your stored vectors (inside a vector) and make sure they all have the same size (if not, add zeros in the vacant spaces):-**

```
template<class TargetClass>
size_t EqualizeVectors(std::vector<std::vector<TargetClass>> &target, const bool equalize = true)
{
    if (target.empty())
        return 0;
    size_t greatest_size = 0;
    for (auto &elem : target)
        for (auto &elem2 : target)
            if (elem.size() > greatest_size)
                greatest_size = elem.size();
            else if (elem.size() > elem2.size())
                greatest_size = elem.size();
    if (equalize)
        for (auto &elem : target)
            for (auto i = 0; i < signed(greatest_size - elem.size()); i++)
                elem.emplace_back(0);
    return greatest_size;
}
```

Now we have a function that will equalize all the vectors to the same sizes, the **target** is the vector you are targeting for this process and **equalize** is just to disable the process of adding zeroes to the spaces (it will only return the value and do nothing else if you change Equalize to false).

**2) Create a function that will sum up all the vectors present in the base vector. (Keep in mind that you are trying to do it in the vertical form so it will be different (such as** `target[i][j]` **becoming** `target[j][i]` ,**etc.):-**

```
template<class TargetClass>
std::vector<TargetClass> GetVectorTotal(std::vector<std::vector<TargetClass>> target)
{
    const auto size = EqualizeVectors(target);
    std::vector<TargetClass> totals;
    for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        TargetClass sum = 0;
        for (auto j = 0; j < signed(target.size()); j++)
            sum += target[j][i];
        totals.emplace_back(sum);
        sum = 0;
    }
    return totals;
}
```

Now what this function does is what you see, adds up all the elements present on the **i** position of each vector in your base vector and returns the resulting vector containing all the sums.

**3) Create a function that will take out the average from the resulting total (now this one is an easy one, and optional too, you can just directly put it in the main function):-**

```
template<class TargetClass>
std::vector<TargetClass> GetVectorAverage(std::vector<std::vector<TargetClass>> &target, const bool omit_zero = true)
{
    std::vector<TargetClass> totals = GetVectorTotal(target);
    if (omit_zero)
        for (auto i = 0; i < signed(totals.size()); i++)
            if (totals[i] == 0)
                totals.erase(totals.begin() + i);
    std::vector<TargetClass> averages(totals.size());
    for (auto i = 0; i < signed(totals.size()); i++)
        averages[i] = totals[i] / target.size();
    return averages;
}
```

This function first checks all the totals from the **total** parameter. The **omit_zero** parameter asks whether you want to remove the total(s) of numbers which are zero. Now here too you *have* to provide `target.size()` instead of `total.size()` in `averages[i] = totals[i] / target.size();` because you are preferring the vertical method.

Now you are all ready to find the average of **any** vector containing as many numbers as you want.

**Example:-**

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> numbers
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6, 7, 8 }
    };
    auto averages = GetVectorAverage(numbers);
    std::cout << "[ ";
    for (auto &elem : averages)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    std::cout << "]";
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> [ 3 4 5 6 ]

Kind regards,

Ruks